# Is there any way to read and compare dates from nested JSON Array of Objects in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column **data** in a Table. The **data** column has JSON stored. It has the following format [image] I want to check if **assignment_end_date** in **user_nodes_assignment** is greater than or equal to some date return that record.

Previously I am able to achieve the equal condition using the following query

```
select id, data 
from "fq_DateUserPerformance" fdup2 
where fdup2.data @> '{"user_node_assignments": [{"assignment_start_date": "2022-03-18T17:09:55.176822+01:00"}]}'::jsonb
```

But I am not able to do the same for greater than or less than. Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Do not post data as images. Pls post your JSON as text,

Comment: Please [do not post a painting of the json data, but the JSON text itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [json path query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH):

```
select id, data 
from "fq_DateUserPerformance" fdup2 
where jsonb_path_match(fdup2.data, '$.user_node_assignments[*].assignment_start_date.datetime() >= "2022-03-18T17:09:55.176822+01:00".datetime()')
```

Comment: When i run this query i get following error
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '(' at or near "(" of jsonpath input
  Position: 93

Comment: Ah, I suppose one doesn't need the `exists` operator here